# Trouble with recursion. Why is this method compiling but crashing when I run it in my driver?

Tags: recursion, binary, drjava

//Recursive method that takes your int, prints that number of stars.
//I know that the first if statement isn't proper java format, but having nStars(n) on the same line as factorial = (n-1) gives me an error while compiling.

```
public class RecursiveMethods {
    int theVal; 
    int factorial;


    public void nStars(int n) {

        if (n > 0) {
            factorial = (n-1);
            nStars(n);
            System.out.print("*");
      }
        else {
            System.out.print( "*");
      }
   }

  // recursively finds the binary of the int and prints the amount of 1s in the binary
    public int numOnes(int x) {

        int theVal = 0;

            if (x == 0) {
                theVal = theVal;
  }

            if (x % 2 == 1) {
                theVal = 1 + theVal;
                x = (x / 2);
                numOnes(x);
  }

            else if (x % 2 == 0) {
                theVal = 0 + theVal;
                x = (x / 2);
                numOnes(x);
  }


            return theVal;
  }

}

// here is the driver (Only done for the * method haven't gotten to numOnes driver)

import java.util.*;

public class RecursiveDriver { 
    private static Object userInput;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       RecursiveDriver rd = new  RecursiveDriver();
       RecursiveMethods rm = new RecursiveMethods();


       System.out.println("How many stars do you want to see?");
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       int n = sc.nextInt();
       rm.nStars(n);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code:

```
public void nStars(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        factorial = (n-1);
        nStars(n);  // <---- Look here
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print( "*");
    }
}
```

Notice that this function calls itself with the same arguments. Therefore:

- When you call `nStars(n)`, it calls `nStars(n)`.
- When that call to `nStars(n)` happens, it calls `nStars(n)`.
- When that call to `nStars(n)` happens, it calls `nStars(n)`.
- When that call to `nStars(n)` happens, it calls `nStars(n)`.
- When that call to `nStars(n)` happens, it calls `nStars(n)`.
- When that call to `nStars(n)` happens, it calls `nStars(n)`.
- ...

Eventually, you'll get a stack overflow from having too many recursive calls active at the same time.

You probably meant to write something like this instead:

```
public void nStars(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        factorial = (n-1);
        nStars(n - 1);  // <---- Look here
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print( "*");
    }
}
```

Now, you're calling `nStars` with argument `n - 1`, so eventually you'll get down to the base case. There's another bug in here, though. (I'll leave it for you to find as an exercise; it's not going to cause a crash)

Hope this helps!